# Are Merino cycling boxers/cycling pants worth the cost?

Tags: frugal, clothes

I can find boxers of various materials such as latex, spandex, nylon, cotton, merino -- now I am totally lost for the reasons to pay about 30 times more for Merino boxers. I am more interested in the material so I may find a cheaper alternative with different name to "bicycle pants". I am particularly interested in products that moves the moisture out and sure marketing like you do not need to clean them sound interesting but not sure whether just marketing (that way I would not need to carry too many extra pants).

Please, help me to find some proper cycling pants/boxer/things.

You can see [here](http://www.backcountry.com/stoic-merino-boxer-brief-mens) an expensive example in Merino.

Comment: They are if you buy Me a pair. ;->

Comment: How many times a week will you wear them? The more you use any tool, the better you are at knowing what you need, and the less cost matters. I'm not familiar with that brand, but $100 to $200 for wool bottoms and tops have been great investments for me. Where do you ride and for how long?

Comment: bmike: 100km per day at least but soon more and soon in much colder. Going as North as I can...

Comment: Those merino boxers you linked to aren't cycling nicks, they're just underwear. You'd still have to wear somethign over the top of them. If you're spending any time in the saddle I'd suggest a proper pair of cycling nicks - with a chamois. That said, I got some cheap merino thermals at Aldi, and they're great. Warm in the wet, but not sweaty like lycra. You can even machine wash them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Those merino boxers you linked to aren't cycling nicks, they're just
>   underwear. You'd still have to wear somethign over the top of them. If
>   you're spending any time in the saddle I'd suggest a proper pair of
>   cycling nicks - with a chamois. That said, I got some cheap merino
>   thermals at Aldi, and they're great. Warm in the wet, but not sweaty
>   like lycra. You can even machine wash them.

I accept this comment, to get this question away from unanswered list. I will remove this if the original commenter makes the comment as answer. I think the comment/answer is good because it cuts the marketing facade into issues such as proper pair of cycling nicks (with a chamois) and machine-washing -- and needless to get some XYZ -branded merino [wf]-ools, even discounters offer proper ones.

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 pairs of Pearl Izumi standard black cycling shorts.  They are a little expensive (for my tastes) -- a basic pair runs about $75-100, depending on where you buy it -- but they wear pretty well.  The oldest pair (which is beginning to come apart and is now just "backup") is about 8 years old and has probably has the equivalent of 5K miles on it (in addition to wearing them while cycling I wear them in the gym on days when I use an exercise bike).

On a week tour I generally carry all 3 pair, and use the two better ones each 3-4 days without washing (with the 3rd as backup, as I said).  (I typically limit washing of the shorts to no more often than once a week anyway, since washing causes more wear on the shorts than riding in them, and I'm that cheap.)  I will rinse out a pair if they get exceptionally sweaty (and dry them on the back rack while riding) but that doesn't happen too often.

Comment: While you are correct about the washing causing wear, if you use correct detergents, and handwash as most manufacturers recommend, it will not cause additional wear. And there are huge health/bacterial issues with riding in a pair of shorts twice without washing. Highly not recommended.

Comment: ...and if you're riding in a group it's just good manners to wear clean shorts.  If your leader is making everyone hold their breath then they really aren't helping the group much ;)

Comment: Handwashing isn't going to happen.